# python partial function definition from doc

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), the following is what's described as the rough equivalent of `partial`'s functionality. I have trouble understanding this code. From the `/` in the parameters to the attribute assignments - these are attributes of the `partial` object - how can they make their way into its definition? Any help pointing me to some resource where this is explained would be appreciated.

```
   def partial(func, /, *args, **keywords):
        def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
            newkeywords = {**keywords, **fkeywords}
            return func(*args, *fargs, **newkeywords)
        newfunc.func = func
        newfunc.args = args
        newfunc.keywords = keywords
        return newfunc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the `/` is new syntax added in Python 3.8.0.  It indicates that the parameters that precede it are positional-only, and may not be specified as keyword arguments.  This allows the implementation to change the parameter name at a later time without risking breaking any calls that refer to it by name (since they're prevented from doing so).

The function `partial` returns a closure which references the arguments that were passed to `partial`.  When invoked, the returned function first constructs the arguments by combining the newly-passed arguments with the ones that were specified earlier, when `partial` was called.  It then passes those constructed arguments to `func`, returning the result of the call.

For example, if you do:

```
f = partial(my_func, 1, 2, x=3, y=4)
```

then `f` is `newfunc`, but taken in the context of the call to `partial`, so when it's called, it will have access to the arguments that you passed.

If you then do:

```
r = f(5, 6, z=7, w=8)
```

Then the following happens:  First, `newfunc` is called as:

```
newfunc(5, 6, z=7, w=8)
```

Within `newfunc`, `fargs` is `(5, 6)` and `fkeywords` is `{'z' : 7, 'w' : 8}`.  It then constructs the combined arguments by combining these with the values of `args` and `keywords` from the call to `partial`, so `args` is `(1, 2)` and `keywords` is `{'x' : 3, 'y' : 4}`.

It then combines these.  It first sets `newkeywords` to `{'x' : 3, 'y' : 4, 'z' : 7, 'w' : 8}`.  It then calls `func`, which is `my_func`, combining the positional arguments in the call itself, so they end up as `(1, 2, 5, 6)`.

The result is equivalent to:

```
r = my_func(1, 2, 5, 6, x=3, y=4, z=7, w=8)
```

So `f` is essentially a wrapper for `my_func` which supplies some of the arguments.

The rest of `partial` is just setting some attributes of `newfunc`.  Those attributes (`func`, `args`, and `keywords`) are available to the caller from the returned function (i.e. `f` in this example).  So you could access them as `f.func`, `f.args`, and `f.keywords`.

Comment: You can also *see* the saved contents in the closure. Given `f = lambda x,y,z: x + y + z` and `fp =  partial(f, 3, y=9)`, look at `[x.cell_contents for x in fp.__closure__]`. (I don't have a good explanation for the actual order used by `__closure__`.)

Comment: @chepner That's interesting.  It looks like it doesn't store the variable name in the cell, but only its value, unless it's stored someplace else that I couldn't find.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for the detailed answer. I didn't know you could set arbitrary attributes to functions.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think it's probably just an implementation detail of CPython. If you look at the generated byte code for `fp`, you can see the integer indices used with the `LOAD_DEREF` instruction. The information stored is sufficient for use by the compiled code, but not designed for introspection.